# unzip a list of archives

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

I need to Unzipped a list of zip archives. These archives are not empty, in each one there are a lot of file. In my directory I have a lot of file zip archive and all have the the name in the same format: batch-download-ccd-1610959358275.zip but change only the numeric part.  I can extract each archive with `unzip` command but if I try to extract all the archives together with this command `unzip *.zip` I get this message (For simplicity I report only the example where I try to extract two archives):

```
Archive:  batch-download-ccd-1610959358275.zip
caution: filename not matched:  batch-download-ccd-1610959397790.zip
```

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unzip` takes only one archive as an argument, the remaining arguments are understood as files inside the archive.

Use a shell loop:

```
for zip in batch-download-ccd-*.zip ; do
    unzip "$zip"
done
```